# JS convert obj to str

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm creating code to convert a string to a dictionary and an array, and to convert an array and a dictionary to a string.

String to array works, String to Obj (dictionary) works, array to text works, but obj to string (text) doesn't. I'm stuck and I don't know how to fix it. I tested the code but the results were not good.

```js
function strToArray(string) {
  let array = [];
  for (var element of string) {
    array.push(element);
  }
  return array;
};

function strToObj(string) {
  let dict = {};
  for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    let letter = string[i];
    if (dict[letter]) {
      dict[letter].push(i);
    } else {
      dict[letter] = [i];
    }
  }
  return dict;
};

function arrayToString(array) {
  let text = "";
  for (var element of array) {
    text = text + element;
  }
  return text;
};

function objToString(obj) {
  let text = "";
  //for(i = 0; i < obj.length; i++){
  //text = text + arrayToString(obj[i]);
  //}
  for (var element in obj) {
    let value = obj[element];

  }
  return text;
};


const ArrayHello = strToArray('hello');
const ObjHello = strToObj('hello');
const HelloArray = arrayToString(ArrayHello);
const HelloObj = objToString(ObjHello);

console.log(ArrayHello);
console.log(ObjHello);
console.log(HelloArray);
console.log(HelloObj);
```

Comment: What *exactly* does "not good results" mean? Are errors or exceptions thrown? Does *anything* happen?

Comment: If I understand what you're trying to do, this is called serialization and deserialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use array to create the string and can reuse `arrayToString()` method and can get the answer easily like following:

```js
function strToArray(string) {
  let array = [];
  for (var element of string) {
    array.push(element);
  }
  return array;
};

function strToObj(string) {
  let dict = {};
  for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    let letter = string[i];
    if (dict[letter]) {
      dict[letter].push(i);
    } else {
      dict[letter] = [i];
    }
  }
  return dict;
};

function arrayToString(array) {
  let text = "";
  for (var element of array) {
    text = text + element;
  }
  return text;
};

function objToString(obj) {
  let text = [];
  
  for (let [key, index] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    for (let i of index) {
      text[i] = key;
    }
  }
  
  return arrayToString(text);
};


const ArrayHello = strToArray('hello');
const ObjHello = strToObj('hello');
const HelloArray = arrayToString(ArrayHello);
const HelloObj = objToString(ObjHello);

console.log(ArrayHello);
console.log(ObjHello);
console.log(HelloArray);
console.log(HelloObj);
```

UPDATE:

You can also use `Array.prototype.join` method to achieve `arrayToString` functionality easily
[[MDN LINK]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

```js
const array = ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'];

const arrayToString = (arr, delimiter = '') => arr.join(delimiter);

console.log(arrayToString(array));
```

Comment: thanks worked, it also log undefined, you know why?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could be done for the `objToString`

```js
function objToString(obj) {
  let text = "";
  let result = [];
  Object.entries(obj).forEach((entry) => {
    entry[1].forEach((ind) => {
      result[ind] = entry[0];
    });
  });
  text = result.join("");
  return text;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```js
function strToArray(string) {
  let array = [];
  for (var element of string) {
    array.push(element);
  }
  return array;
};

function strToObj(string) {
  let dict = {};
  for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    let letter = string[i];
    if (dict[letter]) {
      dict[letter].push(i);
    } else {
      dict[letter] = [i];
    }
  }
  return dict;
};

function arrayToString(array) {
  let text = "";
  for (var element of array) {
    text = text + element;
  }
  return text;
};

function objToString(obj) {
  let text = "";
  
  for (var element in obj) {
   let value = obj[element];
   text+=value//+" ";// in Place of " " you can use any seprator
  }
  return text;
};


const ArrayHello = strToArray('hello');
const ObjHello = strToObj('hello');
const HelloArray = arrayToString(ArrayHello);
const HelloObj = objToString(ObjHello);

console.log(ArrayHello);
console.log(ObjHello);
console.log(HelloArray);
console.log(HelloObj);
```

Comment: Highly doubt they want `,0,1,2,3,4`

Comment: OP wants "HELLO" not numbers

Comment: Now I think Its Ok..

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).